# Android play video button without videoview

Tags: android, video-streaming

I have a simple button, and I wish to play an URL video buy clicking on this button but without a `videoView`. 
 So if I click on the button , the phone will ask which internal player I'll choose to play the video.

Here I was using a `videoView` that was playing the video inside the window of my application but I want it outside :

```
        boutonVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boutonVideo);
        video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(video);

        video.setMediaController(mediaController);
        Uri chemin = Uri.parse("http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp");
        video.setVideoURI(chemin);
        video.start();
```

Thank you,

so here's the code :

```
        boutonVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boutonVideo);
        boutonVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in;
                if (v.getId() == R.id.boutonVideo) {
                    in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse(urlBandeAnnonce));
                    startActivity(in);
                }

            }
        });
```

But it return me an error when I decide to stop the video and return to my activity. 
Here is the AndroidRunTime Error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-30 15:20:16.449: E/AndroidRuntime(2301):
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)

---

#### Solved

So I add finish(); and the error disappear.

Comment: Have you initialized "urlBandeAnnonce"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `Intent` with `ACTION_VIEW` along with the URI to the movie you want to play:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(movieUrl));
startActivity(intent);
```

where `movieUrl` is a string containing the path to the movie.

This may or may not work with internet streams. Haven't tried it with those personally.

Comment: Thanks, I was not able to add an other post so I edit my first topic

Comment: i can't play embded urls even youtube

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked to [Android Api examples](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html)

if you have installed the samples on your pc it is located at (for windows systems)

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-16\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\media
```